# Convert string to Model Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I convert the following string to Model Classes?

```
string temp = "Oliver/Christina=2373400019485 Ortosan/David=2373400019486"
```

Data output:

```
FirstName = Christina
LastName = Oliver
Code = 2373400019485

FirstName = David
LastName = Ortosan
Code = 2373400019486
```

My model class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: String.Split is the way to start...

Comment: Thank you, you can send a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
string temp = "Oliver/Christina=2373400019485 Ortosan/David=2373400019486";
            var PersonstrList = temp.Split(' ');
            List<Test> PersonList = new List<Test>();
            foreach (var p in PersonstrList)
            {
                Test t = new Test();
                t.LastName = p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf("/"));
                t.FirstName = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("/"), p.IndexOf("/") - p.IndexOf("="));
                t.Code = p.Substring(p.IndexOf("="));
                PersonList.Add(t);
            }
```

first split string by space (' ') and then use each of array elemets as a person. by substring we can split properties of each person.